# Duplicate question one with a (unaccepted) answer the other with none

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I came accross to very similar questions.

The first is older, the comments on the question helped the Q find its own A. But the Answer was never marked as excepted: [Cannot print from LibreOffice, but can from a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207281/cannot-print-from-libreoffice-but-can-from-a-terminal)

The second was written pretty recently and I commented that it was similar to the first: [Printer works but docs can only print to file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370881/printer-works-but-docs-can-only-print-to-file)

I was reminded by another user that the answer on the first questions isn't very good, to which I agree. Still: I would like to mark the second beeing a duplicate of the first. Currently this isn't possible because the answer was not marked as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An upvote to the answer will make it possible to close the other one against it.

The criteria for being able to use a question as the target of a duplicate closure are the same as for the system to consider a question answered: it must have at least one answer with a positive score, or an accepted answer with any score (or both).

If you are not willing to upvote the answer in its current state, perhaps you are able to improve it with an edit, possibly by adding information from the comments.

Comment: Now that I look at the comments of the old question I don't see anything especially enlightening to add to the answer. He most *probably* added it to CUPS with the system settings but this all feels somewhat ... meh :-/ I've had similar issues printing over LibreOffice, but all this is somewhat in the past. Being as undecided  as I am right now. I tend to not touch either question.

Comment: *I tend to not touch either question.* the alternative is use a `Close -> Needs Details or Clarity` or `Community Specific -> Other` with an appropriate comment.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood @MadMike . If you don't think the answer is good enough for the OP of the new question, then why do you want to close it at all? Perhaps a better answer will be posted and the old question can be closed against the new one. **24601** I do not support the use of custom close reasons for this purpose and the question should only be closed as *Needs Details or Clarity* if it does in fact need further details or clarification (looks like that may be the case with this particular question (what printer is it?) but I'm speaking generally)